# Is it possible to download from the internet using filezilla?

Tags: ssh, ftp, vsftpd, filezilla

I am trying to set up a packet program for my amateur radio hobby. I came across this website:http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/AX25-HOWTO/x94.html. In it there are three software programs with the ftp protocol:

```
ftp://hams.sourceforge.net/pub/hams/ax25/libax25-0.0.7.tar.gz

ftp://hams.sourceforge.net/pub/hams/ax25/ax25-tools-0.0.6.tar.gz

ftp://hams.sourceforge.net/pub/hams/ax25/ax25-apps-0.0.4.tar.gz
```

My question is how you you download from the internet using ftp? I disabled the firewalls, but it still isn't working. Again, thank you all for your help in advance, it is very appreciated.

Comment: The links are dead. The document linking to them are outdated.

Comment: Ok so the instructions I found would have worked probably. I will have to try to find updated links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This HOWTO is quite old (it's from 2001) and the FTP links don't work any more.

But Ubuntu has the packages `ax25-apps`, `ax25-tools`, and `libax25` in the official repositories and I guess this are those programs from the HOWTO. So you can just install them via Software Center or `apt-get`.